# Drush make Distribution throwing errors: exec() unable to fork bootstrap.inc:636

Tags: 7, distributions, drush

I'm using [DrupalPro VM](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalpro) and trying to do a `drush make` on the distribution [One Page CV](https://drupal.org/project/onepagecv).

I build the distribution:

```
sudo drush make onepagecv.make -y
```

But I'm getting the following errors during the make and crashes my terminal. I logged the install process and it seems to stop at the following.

Here is the log:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to some resources limit or [temporary glitch](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/292). So first try to restart your Apache.

If this won't help, make sure that you've necessary requirements to run drush (which is either [curl or wget](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105434/curl-nor-wget-was-found)).

Otherwise it could be some resource limitation on your environment. E.g. check for `ulimit -a` or `kern.maxprocs`.

If there is still problem, please add `-v` for verbose mode or `-d` for debug messages for `drush`, you could more easily track the issue.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Classic turn it off and on again solution :)